# SQL Server 2008 Import RawData Into Table based on Filename

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

I have a table with ZIP files saved as RawData.  I've extracted the ZIP files using BCP, then unzipped them using 7-zip.  The Unzipped files are RTF files that are given the ID number for the name.  For example 56.rtf, 65.rtf, etc.  My question is how do I import the raw RTF data into a row in a table based on the file name?  I've been playing with BULK INSERT and that gets the data into a table with one column, but how do I know which row in the table corresponds to which file so it can be retrieved with a query? I'm fairly new at this so try to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: Show us what you have so far.  That will make it easier for us to explain the options to you without us having to make a lot of assumptions and guesses about how you are doing it now.

Comment: I used SSIS to get the files imported and there is a FileName component within SSIS that can be passed to a table.  The issue I'm having with that is when I pass it to the table it isn't giving me the file name, just "C" which is part of the path, I assume it's having an issue with the characters in the filepath.

Comment: Problem solved using SSIS.  I just had to tweak some things from the explanation at this link.  http://codejotter.wordpress.com/2010/04/06/importing-multiple-text-files-using-ssis/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use SSIS for this task. If you create a data flow inside a for each file loop, then you can loop over all the files in a folder and capture the file name of each file in a SSIS variable, and then insert this into a second column. Your package st,rupture would be as follows:

MyPackage
    MyForEachLoop
        MyDataFlowTask
            MyFlatFileSource
            MyOLEDBDestination

Comment: I actually went the SSIS route, using this link as a reference. http://codejotter.wordpress.com/2010/04/06/importing-multiple-text-files-using-ssis/